# Create a profile bar with the style of linkedin

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, frontend

```
https://jsfiddle.net/yxsc3cqy/
```

Couldn't create a look n feel like the linked in profil page, whatever row i create is hidden by the previous row. What is the problem and how can i get a better styling. Thanks

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110" alt="" class="myProfilPic">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/138x10" alt=""  class="coverPic">
    <div class="seperator"></div>
  </div>



.myProfilPic{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 90px 0px 0px 130px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #BADA55;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.seperator{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height:3px;
    width:100vw;
    background:#000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 138px;
}
.coverPic{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 138px;
    width:100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new rows you create are being hidden by the previous because the `position` of the elements inside the row, specifically the `.coverPic` element, is set to `absolute`.

**The Solution**

Change the position of the `.coverPic` element like so:

```
    .coverPic {
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        height: 138px;
        width:100vw;
    }
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxsc3cqy/1/

Read more about positioning elements in CSS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example)